# How to configure webpack hot reload to work inside Docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, symfony, npm, webpack

I'm working on a Symfony 4 project for months, and I want to Dockerize it.

I make everything work except Webpack, I use it to compile my `.scss` and `.js` files with the `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` command.

Actually webpack does not listen changes I do in a `.scss` or `.js` file for example.

Here is my config, I surely miss something in my files.

My `docker-compose.yml` :

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysql:
     image: mysql:8.0
     command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
     restart: on-failure
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - '8004:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOSTS: mysql
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '../.:/usr/src/app'
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .env
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.0-alpine
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - '../public:/usr/src/app'
      - './nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    depends_on:
      - php
  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: node/Dockerfile
    volumes:
       - '../.:/usr/src/app'
    command: npm run watch
```

My `Dockerfile` for Node Image :

```
FROM node:12.10.0

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        curl

RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
        echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

CMD ["npm", "run", "watch"]
```

My `webpack.config.js` :

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')

    .splitEntryChunks()

    .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    .enableSassLoader()

    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .configureBabel(() => {}, {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3
    })

    .addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: './assets/pictures', to: 'pictures' }
    ]))
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

// module.exports = {
//   mode: 'development',
//   devServer: {
//     port: 80,
//     host: '0.0.0.0',
//     disableHostCheck: true,
//     watchOptions: {
//       ignored: /node_modules/,
//       poll: 1000,
//       aggregateTimeout: 1000
//     }
//   }
// }
```

As you can see I already tried some thing in `webpack.config.js`, I saw many things about `watchOptions` but I didn't get it.

And here is my project's organisation :

[project's organisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC3EL.png)

I want to be able to launch my Docker with Webpack listening any change I do in real time.

Here is the command console after running `docker-compose up`:

[console command docker-compose up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dde9h.png)

If you have some advise to improve my Docker environment, I take it all !

Thank you !

Comment: If you're running Windows with WSL2, then file change events aren't sent to the container if the files are stored in the Windows file system. The docs say "Linux containers only receive file change events (“inotify events”) if the original files are stored in the Linux filesystem. For example, some web development workflows rely on inotify events for automatic reloading when files have changed." https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/

Comment: Hello @HansKilian, yes i forgot to said it, i am running on a Windows 10 with Docker Desktop application. And yes i use WSL2. My project is stored on my main disk but i think i don't get all your explanations. I have to check this "inotify events" to do the job ? I am beginner with Docker :/

Comment: This goes into a bit more detail why it doesn't work and how you can get around it. Personally I thought storing my files in the WSL filesystem was too big a hassle and I gave up on getting it to work. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/docker-desktop-on-wsl2-the-problem-with-mixing-file-systems-a8b5dcd79b22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i think i solved my issue,

I followed @Rufinus answer; i had to `docker-compose up` in a first console command, open a second console command and execute `winpty docker-compose exec node yarn watch` but for some reason i had issue with `node-sass` compatibility : i mounted my node_module (windows 10) folder into the container (Linux).

So i opened my node CLI container and execute `npm rebuild node-sass` to solve this and finally it worked !

But i don't know why, my current solution is to execute `npm run watch` on my local folders (like i used to do it before Dockerizing all my application) and it re-builds assets when i change `.scss` or `.js` file.

Comment: i comment here - but includes your comment on my answer too. First, no i code on linux only - so with win some things can be different. second - after every change off docker-compose.yml you have do `docker-compose up -d`. my node container config is just a container hanging around. and waiting for stuff to do. My wepack js is mostly default. (symfony/webpack).

Comment: my normal workflow after `docker-compose up -d` is to install the npm/yarn pkg, then start the watcher. this runs in a own console window - so i see if there is any error - and its easier to ctrl+c and start again if something is not working.

Answer (score 2):

i just use this:

docker-compose.yml:

```
node:
    image: node:16-alpine3.13
    working_dir: /var/www/app
    user: "$USERID"
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/app
    tty: true
```

and `docker-compose exec node yarn watch`

working as expected.

Comment: Hello @Rufinus, thank you for your answer, i changed my docker-compose.yml with your answer but when do i launch this command ?
Is this command replace the docker-compose up or i open another console command and execute it when my containers are up ?

Are you on Windows 10 too ? And did you configure something more inside your webpack.config.js file ? 

I am a bit lost actually